# What does the last icon mean in Far Cry 4 trading post interface?

Tags: far-cry-4

[image: Far Cry 4 trading post]

Where my mouse icon is, the number 53, what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of items currently in your bag

Including, if you still have it, your mom's letter